# Shopping cart with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, sql, ajax

I build a cart for an ecommerce website, and I want to know if I did well.

I want to record the changes in the DB and display the information from the DB to the customer. To be sure that what he sees is the good information. I use an ajax request and JSON to do so.

Please give me your comments. I especially want to know is my code safe?

The client side:

```
    function save_to_db(cartId, newQuantity) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "updateCart.php",
    data: "cartId=" + cartId + "&newQuantity=" + newQuantity + "&memberId=" + <?php echo $memberId?>,
    type: 'post',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
      if (response === "Empty cart") {
        $("#total-quantity").text(0);
        $("#total-price").text(0);
        $("#shopping-cart-table").html("<h2><b style='color:red'>Your cart is empty.</b></h2>");
      }

      if (newQuantity == 0) {
        $("#item-container-" + cartId).remove();
      }

      var totalQuantity = 0;
      var totalItemPrice = 0;
      $.each(response, function(key, cartDetails) {
        totalItemPrice = totalItemPrice + parseInt(cartDetails.price) * parseInt(cartDetails.quantity);
        totalQuantity = totalQuantity + parseInt(cartDetails.quantity);

        if (cartDetails.cartId == cartId) {
          $("#input-quantity-" + cartId).val(cartDetails.quantity);
          $("#cart-price-" + cartId).text("$" + cartDetails.price * cartDetails.quantity);
        }
      });

      $("#total-quantity").text(totalQuantity);
      $("#total-price").text(totalItemPrice);
      $("#total-price-foot").text(totalItemPrice);
    }
  });
}
```

The server side:

```
    <?php
require 'connectDB.php';

$memberId = $_POST["memberId"];

if($_POST["newQuantity"] == 0){
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn,"DELETE FROM tbl_cart WHERE id = ? AND member_id = ?");

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ii", $_POST["cartId"], $memberId);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
elseif ($_POST["newQuantity"] == 1 || $_POST["newQuantity"] == -1) {
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn,"UPDATE tbl_cart SET quantity =
        (CASE WHEN quantity + ? > 0 THEN quantity + ? ELSE quantity END)
        WHERE id= ? AND member_id = ?");

        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "iiii",
            $_POST["newQuantity"],
            $_POST["newQuantity"],
            $_POST["cartId"],
            $memberId);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
    }

    if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn,"SELECT tbl_product.id, tbl_product.price, tbl_cart.quantity, tbl_cart.id
        AS cartId FROM tbl_product, tbl_cart WHERE tbl_product.id = tbl_cart.product_id AND tbl_cart.member_id = ?")) {

            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "i", $memberId);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);

            $result = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
                $cartDetails[] = $row;
            }

            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }


        if(isset($cartDetails)){
            $response = json_encode($cartDetails);
            echo $response;
        }
        else{
            $response = json_encode("Empty cart");
            echo $response;
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your action processing script, you should, before doing anything else, validate the input.  If anything is outside of the expected range of values, you should immediately return a failure response.

I will also urge you to write your query functions in object-oriented syntax rather than procedural because it is more brief and easier to read (IMO).

Since you are returning json, I recommend that you always return some sensibly keyed objects containing predictable data types for your javascript to handle.  You may consider `status`, `message`, and `data` as included keys no matter the outcome, this will make the javascript handling much cleaner.

The following rewrite will exercise reduced variable generation, and less complex & more readable logic and queries.

The action processing script:

```
if (empty($_POST["memberId"]) ||
    empty($_POST["cartId"]) ||
    !isset($_POST["newQuantity"]) ||
    !ctype_digit($_POST["memberId"]) ||
    !ctype_digit($_POST["cartId"]) ||
    !in_array($_POST["newQuantity"], [-1, 0, 1])
) {
    exit(json_encode(['status' => 'fail',
                      'message' => 'Missing/Invalid request data',
                      'data' => []]));
}

require 'connectDB.php';  // adjust this to OO style instead of procedure

if (!$_POST["newQuantity"]) {
    $query = "DELETE FROM tbl_cart WHERE id = ? AND member_id = ?";
} elseif ($_POST["newQuantity"] == 1) {
    $query = "UPDATE tbl_cart SET quantity = quantity + 1 WHERE id = ? AND member_id = ?";
} else {
    $query = "UPDATE tbl_cart SET quantity = quantity - 1 WHERE quantity > 0 AND id = ? AND member_id = ?";
}
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $_POST["cartId"], $_POST["memberId"]);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();

$stmt = $conn->prepare($conn, "SELECT p.id, p.price, c.quantity, c.id AS cartId 
                               FROM tbl_product AS p
                               INNER JOIN tbl_cart AS c on p.id = c.product_id
                               WHERE c.member_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST["memberId"]);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
exit(json_encode(['status' => 'pass',
                  'message' => 'Shopping cart updated',
                  'data' => $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC)]));
```

Now you javascript can be adjusted to process these very useful, meaningful, and always-available values (which ALWAYS have the same data type) via:

- `response.status` (string)
- `response.message`(string)
- `response.data`(an empty or multi-dimensional array)

Answer (score 1):

So far what I see is you aren't either casting nor sanitizing your `$_POST` variables but simply placing them into your SQL statement - it's better you perform some sort of filtering on those arguments (e.g. remove whitespaces, fixing invalid characters like `'\'` to `'\\'`, etc.) and ensure you are passing numbers (according to your example you'd maybe use `intval()`), not a string or `NULL` value (unless that's intended, which I doubt).

In addition, the server-end should separate the database calls from parsing and filtering content - either as separate functions, files and/or both; if you were going the OOP route, then you'd set up a class(es) for either activity and use a layering system like MVC, N-Tier, MVVC.

All of this goes into making your code more reusable and easier to manage plus adds a layer of security via "Abstraction".